# SQL Server subquery result output

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to create a result that lists all clients added to database yesterday and then a separate column for the same set of clients but only those without an email address, so we can see which CSR rep isn't adding email addresses, i am having trouble writing a subquery for counts.  Below is my code, its using two tables CLIENT and CONTACT they join on ACCT_NO field

I am using SQL Server Management Studio

```
select 
    count(distinct c.acct_no) as Total, ADDED_BY 
from 
    client c
inner join 
    (select 
         count(distinct ct.acct_no) acct_NO 
     from 
         contact CT 
     inner join 
         client on client.acct_no = ct.ACCT_NO 
                and ct.EMAILADDR1 = ''
                and ct.[PRIMARY] = 'A' 
     group by 
         ct.ACCT_NO) x on c.ACCT_NO = x.acct_NO 
where 
    c.DATE_ADDED = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE()-10, 121)
group by 
    c.ADDED_BY
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(distinct case ...` for a conditional sum, like:

```
select  ADDED_BY
,       count(distinct case when client.EMAILADDR1 is null then client.ACCT_NO end) 
            as TotalWithoutMail
,       count(distinct case when client.EMAILADDR1 is not null then client.ACCT_NO end) 
            as TotalWithMail
from    contact
jon     client
on      client.ACCT_NO = contact.ACCT_NO
group by
        ADDED_BY
```

Comment: This isn't giving me expected results, i was looking for columns that would look like  ADDED_BY, TOTAL CLIENTS ADDED, TOTAL CLIENTS ADDED WITH NO EMAIL

Comment: MADE A FEW TWEAKS BUT ITS WORKING AS EXPECTED NOW, THANK YOU.